# Can't order wordpress posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I have there the code I'm using, and I'm trying to get the posts in the order of the IDs from the `$menus` array but don't do that, he gave me the posts from the newest to oldest...I have tried to use `order` with `DESC` but the array did not change.

```
$menus = array(105, 54, 111);
       $args = array(
        'post__in' => $menus,
        'orderby' => 'ID',
        'order'   => 'DESC',
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
    $i = 1;
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
    do_action('fwp_before_post_content');
        get_template_part('extend-helpers/' . $layout);
    do_action('fwp_after_post_content');
    $i++;
    endwhile;
    else:
        get_template_part('extend-helpers/content', 'none');
    endif;
```

UPDATE:

The posts are from different categories.

UPDATE II:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.ID IN (105,54,111) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') ORDER BY wp_posts.menu_order, FIELD( wp_posts.ID, 105,54,111 ) LIMIT 0, 1000"
```

Why I have `ORDER BY wp_posts.menu_order`? because in `$args` I don't have orderby menu_order..

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the "orderby" item in the args you pass WP_Query.

[You can find the documentation here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters)

Comment: I've tried to use orderby and order togheter..but nothing changed

Comment: Can you add the code with the order by. Note that ID is with upper case.

Comment: Can you change the orderby value to 'post__in' instead of ID.

Comment: I've tried:( but nothing...I have a new update on the post

Comment: Check in the code if there is any "pre_get_posts" hook setup that could be altering the query variable before it is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the WP_query loop? https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mastering-wp_query-using-the-loop--cms-23031. It uses $args=ASC and DSC and 'orderby ' =>'id' too.

Comment: I want to orderby the ids from my array...I have tried your solution..but nothing

Answer (score 0):

for the first part, you want to use **post__in also in orderby line** as Juan suggested in his comment. From the documentation: *'post__in' - Preserve post ID order given in the 'post__in' array. So, your code should look like this*

```
    $menus = array(55, 53, 57); // I have used mine ids
    $args = array(
        'post__in' => $menus,
        'orderby' => 'post__in',
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

For the second part, which is more important, why do you have ORDER BY wp_posts.menu_order. You can find answer also in comments. The query is being altered by something (theme or plugin), check pre_get_posts hook, try switching theme, etc.

I have tested this code and it is working, so it is ordering posts as they are in array $menus.